# Что представляет собой еженедельная новостная рассылка? Кто ее формирует?

Tags: поддержка, faq

У каждого сайта Stack Exchange есть своя еженедельная новостная рассылка по электронной почте.

Что входит в такую новостную рассылку? Кто её составляет? Что в нее попадает? Как можно подписаться на новостную рассылку или отписаться от рассылки?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### Что представляет собой еженедельная новостная рассылка, и кто ее формирует?

Новостная рассылка – это электронное письмо, которое каждую неделю отправляется всем, кто подписался на рассылку. Рассылка создана специально для участников, которые хотят быть в курсе всех новостей любимого сайта, но  не имеют возможности часто заходить на сайт. Содержимое для новостной рассылки автоматически отбирается системой.

У каждого сайта сети есть своя собственная новостная рассылка, она включает в себя краткий обзор следующего:

- лучшие новые вопросы недели;
- подборка интересных вопросов предыдущих недель;
- подборка неотвеченных вопросов предыдущих недель.

В некоторых случаях рассылка может также включать в себя важные сообщения от сотрудников и модераторов Stack Exchange, содержащие, к примеру, информацию о проводимых выборов в модераторы.

### Как выглядит новостная рассылка?

Если вам хочется взглянуть на то, как будет выглядеть еженедельная новостная рассылка, прежде чем подписаться на нее, проще всего это можно сделать, зайдя на [страницу новостных рассылок](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters). На ней представлен список всех сайтов Stack Exchange. Справа от этого списка — ссылки для подписки на рассылку, а так же для предварительного просмотра шаблона письма. Пройдя по ссылке для предварительного просмотра, вы увидите последнюю отправленную на данный момент новостную рассылку.

### Как можно подписаться на новостную рассылку?

- **В учетной записи участника**

  Зайдите в свою учетную запись, нажмите на кнопку «Править», а затем на кнопку «Параметры» в левой части страницы. Под разделом «Подписка на вопросы и ответы» вы увидите раздел «Новостная рассылка». Для того, чтобы подписаться на рассылку, просто установите флажок «Отправлять мне еженедельную новостную рассылку».

  Обратите внимание на то, что для подписки на рассылку в учетной записи необходимо быть зарегистрированным участником.
- **В списке [всех новостных рассылок](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters)**

  Проще простого — откройте гигантский список сайтов Stack Exchange: рядом с каждым из них вы увидите кнопки «Подписаться на рассылку» и «Предварительный просмотр рассылки». Просто нажмите кнопку «Подписаться» возле названия сайта, новостную рассылку которого вы хотите получать. Анонимным пользователям будет предложено войти в систему, создать учетную запись либо ввести адрес электронной почты, на который они
  хотели бы получать рассылку.
- **Блок в боковой панели**

  Иногда на некоторых сайтах в боковой панели справа отображаются объявления, рекламирующие еженедельную новостную рассылку. Они выглядят примерно так:

  [image: Пример объявления]

  Вы можете нажать на кнопку «Подписаться» в объявлении, после чего появится всплывающее окно. Если вы уже вошли в систему, вы будете автоматически подписаны на новостную рассылку. Если же нет, вам будет предложено войти в систему, создать учетную запись либо ввести адрес электронной почты, на который вы бы хотели получать рассылку.

### Как можно отписаться от новостной рассылки?

Внизу каждого письма, получаемого вами в рамках новостной рассылки, расположена кнопка «Отписаться от новостной рассылки» — это, безусловно, самый простой способ отменить подписку на рассылку.

Если вам нужно настроить несколько подписок, вы можете сделать это, зайдя в ваш профиль на сайте [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) и затем нажав на вкладку «Newsletters» (видна только вам). На этой вкладке отображается список всех действующих подписок, включающих как фильтры по меткам, так и новостные рассылки, а также кнопки, с помощью которых можно отписаться от любой из подписок.